# change language in android studio not saved

Tags: android

When i change the language in my project changed but when i close project and reopen  the language is default.

How to check this problem?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {
private Locale myLocale;
private Button btn_en, btn_ku,btn_ar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadLocale();

    this.btn_en = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_en);
    this.btn_ku = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ku);
    this.btn_ar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ar);

    this.btn_en.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.btn_ku.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.btn_ar.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void loadLocale()
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);


}


public void changeLang(String lang)
{
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    //updateTexts();


}

public void saveLocale(String lang)
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.commit();

}


private void updateTexts()
{
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    String lang = "en";
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_en:
            lang = "en";
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

            break;
        case R.id.btn_ku:
            lang = "fa";
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

            break;

        case R.id.btn_ar:
            lang = "ar";
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    changeLang(lang);

}}
```

Comment: Not sure but maybe its just a simple case of adding (android:configChanges="locale") in your manifest to make the language changes -- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: :( i test this code but its not check my problem i change language in my apk changed but when i close the program then started the program the supportRTL is changed but language not changed but when i go to another activity the load local is worked but the first thing is not worked plz help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Call loadLocale method in onResume() it will work.

Because onCreate() method called first , if you paused the activity by  going to home screen or by launching another activity, onPause() method called.

If you resume the app again means  it will call onCreate() method(already got destroyed) otherwise it call  onResume() only

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
loadLocale();
}
```

Comment: :( the same thing i using the method onResume()
how to another solution sasikumar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , the solution for me was to set new locale every time in oncreate() of all activities, before setContentView()!
like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadLanguage();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_avval);
}
private void loadLanguage()
{
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        String lng = Application.instance().settings.getString("deflang", "def");
        if (!lng.equalsIgnoreCase("def")) {
            Resources res = this.getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            Locale locale = new Locale(lng);
            conf.setLocale(locale); // API 17+ only.
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
        }
    }
}
```